# Python pyaudio input audio streaming error

Tags: python, pyaudio, ubuntu-20.04

I am using PyAudio on Ubuntu 20.04, and trying to obtain a stream of audio data from input microphone.

I can stream audio using PyAudio object and can query host api and device info from my jupyter notebook, but get an error when I use the code wrapped in a python file from the terminal window directly. I have checked the presence of pyaudio package on the terminal environment, still get an error.

Code:

```py
import pyaudio

# start pyaudio instance
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
pa.get_default_host_api_info()
```

Jupyter Notebook:

```sh
{'index': 0,
 'structVersion': 1,
 'type': 8,
 'name': 'ALSA',
 'deviceCount': 23,
 'defaultInputDevice': 22,
 'defaultOutputDevice': 22}
```

Terminal error:

```sh
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2642:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
ALSA lib pcm_route.c:869:(find_matching_chmap) Found no matching channel map
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping unlock
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
```

How can I ensure that any code snippet with PyAudio object works well on the terminal? Am I missing any specific setting on the terminal?

Comment: show code which makes problem.

Comment: code should work without any settings  - if you run on the same local computer.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: it doesn't have to be error but only logs which shows how module was checking different devices. I see simular logs on my Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) but at the end I see information like you see in Notebook. But you have to remeber that in script you have to use `print()` to see text on screen - `print(pa.get_default_host_api_info())`. Notebook automatically display all strings from commands.

Comment: @furas it's not an error message I see, but log. You are right, I should use print in the script and it worked. Thanks for pointing it out.